# How can I copy AWS s3 objects that are Last Modified on a particular date? I have a bucket with millions of objects

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-interface

We store thousands of objects every day. I just want to copy objects for a single day using CLI or AWS nodejs SDK

I am trying this script but It takes too much time

```
#!/bin/bash

SOURCE_BUCKET="b1"
DESTINATION_BUCKET="b2"

content=$(aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket $SOURCE_BUCKET  --query 'Contents[?contains(LastModified, `2022-11-22`)]' | jq -r ".[].Key")

for file in $content;
do
    aws s3api copy-object --copy-source $SOURCE_BUCKET/$file --key $file --bucket $DESTINATION_BUCKET | jq
done
```

Comment: Assuming all the objects are within the bucket exist within the same partition (folder), then I dont see any other way to do it than scanning all objects. However, if the data is partitioned on date for example, then you can just fetch the data within the partition.

Answer (score 0):

A bucket with a large number of objects (100,000+) will be difficult to use with `ListObjects()` because each API call will only return 1000 objects. Thus, a bucket with 1 million objects would require 1000 API calls.

Some ways to make it faster:

- Only list a particular **Prefix** (folder) -- for example, store each day's files in a separate path
- Use [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html) to provide a daily CSV file listing all objects, so you don't need to list the bucket yourself
- Trigger an AWS Lambda function when a new object is created and **store the object details in a database**, then query that database instead of using `ListObjects()`
- Trigger an AWS Lambda function when a new object is created and copy the object to a different folder organised by day (or perhaps one folder for 'latest' files that you can download and then delete)

**Bottom line:** Don't call `ListObjects()` on a bucket with millions of objects. Get creative.